# What is the equivalent of C's #define when specifying an array size in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am starting to learn Rust and I have a background in C.

I am trying to convert the following code snippet from C to Rust. The code defines an array of `uint8_t` with a size that is defined at compile time.

```
#define GRID_SIZE  100

uint8_t grid[GRID_SIZE];
memset (grid, 0x00, GRID_SIZE);
```

I have tried the following in Rust

```
let grid_size: i32 = 10;
let mut grid: [i32; grid_size] = [0; grid_size];
```

the compiler complains that `` error: use of undeclared type name `grid_size` [E0412] ``

Looking up the error E0412 does not provide me with any clue. Is this possible in Rust?

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25474152/155423.

Comment: related issue on uninformative error message in array type length: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24414

Comment: Did you really type `[i32::grid_size]` or is it `[i32; grid_size]`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I tried both suggestions and two different error messages were given by the compiler.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I double check again. The error reported of "undeclared type" is for `[i32; grid_size]`. I will update the question.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks for the pickup. Corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust only allows arrays of compile-time fixed size (dynamically sized spans of the same sized thing in memory are called slices and only available by reference into another container, like a `Vec`). Also, when instantiating them, it wants an unsigned type like `usize`, not an `i32`. Try

```
const GRID_SIZE: usize = 10;

fn main() {
    let mut grid: [i32; GRID_SIZE] = [0; GRID_SIZE];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixes it. I made the mistake in a couple of spots. First, I should have used a const so that size of the array is constant. The second mistake is that Iuse i32 instead of the usize.